# How to paginate information obtained from a query to a custom table?

Tags: database, query, pagination

I am building a small application which consults a registration group of a bd in wordpress, the code is as follows.

```
function opt_menu_cactaceas() {
    global $wpdb;
    $tabla_aspirantes = $wpdb->prefix . 'cactaceas2';
    echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Lista de aspirantes</h1>';
    echo '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">';
    echo '<thead><tr><th width="70%">Nombre Cientifico</th><th width="30%">Imagen</th></tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody id="the-list">';
    $aspirantes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabla_aspirantes");
    foreach ( $aspirantes as $aspirante ) {

        $genero = esc_textarea($aspirante->genero);
        $especie = esc_textarea($aspirante->especie);
        $subespecie = esc_textarea($aspirante->subespecie);
        $autor = esc_textarea($aspirante->autor);

        if ( $subespecie == '' ):

            $nombreCactacea = "<i>$genero $especie</i> $autor";
        else: 
            $nombreCactacea = "<i>$genero $especie</i> subsp. <i>$subespecie</i> $autor";

        endif;

        $imagen_cactus = wp_get_attachment_image( 263, 'thumbnail' );

        echo "<tr><td><a href='#' title='$motivacion'>$nombreCactacea</a></td><td>$imagen_cactus</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</tbody></table></div>';
}
```

As you can see in the image, the records are loaded but the navigation bar extends so much since it is showing all the records directly.

[image]

when obtaining the data these are shown directly on the page but there are 268 records so my query is the way in which **I could paginate all these records since I want them to be shown for example on pages of 20 records each.**

Answer (score -1):

You can use wordpress query args options. I hope this will help you.

```
// WP_Query arguments
   $args = array (
     'nopaging'               => false,
     'posts_per_page'         => '5',
);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```